# how to set timezone in ejb on weblogic

Tags: timezone, ejb, weblogic11g

I have a third party application with a known bug in their date handling. I can work around the bug by ensuring the timezone is UTC.
The application is an EJB in an ear which we deploy on Weblogic 11g.
To date I have managed this by setting the default timezone for the server to UTC.
However, I now want to deploy this application on server where other applications exist that require a different default timezone.
Is there any way to specify timezone = UTC for this application only?
(I have limited access to the workings of the EJB i.e. there are some hooks for user provided java code)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the default timezone each time the EJB starts? (if that's possible with your hooks)

```
// create time zone object 
java.util.TimeZone tzone = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");  
// set time zone default
java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(tzone);
```

List of possible timezones and names:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IANA_time_zones

Comment: I couldn't find any hook for completion of ejb processing i.e. to reset TZ. Couldn't find any way to dedicate specific threads to ejb either, so ended up, having the client code calculate the expected TZ "error" and offsetting this. Yuck, and only works when client and server share the same TZ database. Yuck yuck and double yuck, but the problem is gone for now,

Comment: That is indeed yuck. I don't know if it's an option for you to deploy just about anything on the server, but you could also deploy a simple service on the server that would just return the timezone. That way your client could call that service instead of having to use the same TZ database. This is obviously still yucky with unnecessary overhead.